# How to write a Junit testCase to check the method closeStatement?

Tags: java, jdbc, junit

package com.gs.sybase;
All imports done

```
public class SybaseDBConnection {

    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SybaseDBConnection.class);

    public static Properties prop = null;

    // This block is responsible for loading the sybase.properties file
    static {
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(SybaseDBConnection.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("com/gs/properties/sybase.properties"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception occured : FileNotFoundException : "
                    + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err
                    .println("Exception occured while loading the properties file");
            System.err.println("Exception occured : IOException : "
                    + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /
    public static Connection getConnection(String databaseType)
            throws MigrationException {

        Connection conn = null;
        String driver = null;
        String url = null;
        String user = null;
        String password = null;

        try {

            driver = prop.getProperty("sybase." + databaseType
                    + ".driverClassName");
            url = prop.getProperty("sybase." + databaseType + ".url");
            user = prop.getProperty("sybase." + databaseType + ".username");
            password = prop.getProperty("sybase." + databaseType + ".password");

            SybDriver sybDriver = (SybDriver) Class.forName(driver)
                    .newInstance();
            sybDriver.setVersion(com.sybase.jdbcx.SybDriver.VERSION_LATEST);
            DriverManager.registerDriver(sybDriver);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Exception occured : SQLException : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new MigrationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Exception occured : InstantiationException : "
                            + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new MigrationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Exception occured : IllegalAccessException : "
                            + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new MigrationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Exception occured : ClassNotFoundException : "
                            + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new MigrationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return conn;
    }


    public static void closeConnection(Connection conn)
            throws MigrationException {
        try {
            if (null != conn) {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Exception occured : SQLException : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new MigrationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


    public static void closeResultset(ResultSet rs) throws MigrationException {
        try {
            if (null != rs) {
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Exception occured : SQLException : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new MigrationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


    public static void closePreparedStatement(PreparedStatement pstmt)
            throws MigrationException {
        try {
            if (null != pstmt) {
                pstmt.close();
                pstmt = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Exception occured : SQLException : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new MigrationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static void closeStatement(Statement stmt) throws MigrationException {
        try {
            if (null != stmt) {
                stmt.close();
                stmt = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Exception occured : SQLException : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new MigrationException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


    public static String getProperty(String property) {
        return prop.getProperty(property);
    }

}
```

For the same code. I have written a Junit testCase to test the method closeStatement()

```
@Before
public void openConnBeforeStmtTestASE() throws SQLException, MigrationException {
    conn = SybaseDBConnection.getConnection("iq");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
}


@Test
public void testCloseStatementASE() throws SQLException, MigrationException {
SybaseDBConnection.closeStatement(stmt);
Assert.assertNull(stmt);
SybaseDBConnection.closeConnection(conn);

}
```

The test fails and shows

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Expected: <null> but was: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement@6a13a848
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:22)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:277)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:268)
    at com.gs.test.SybaseDBConnectionTest.testCloseStatementASE(SybaseDBConnectionTest.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Please can you explain the reason for this?? As per my knowledge The test should pass because stmt is null.

Comment: I am not sure if a closed statement is null, since you can test a statement with isClosed() - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#isClosed%28%29

Comment: maybe it's null if you close the connection, not the statement

Comment: First thing I'd do is use a debugger to see what is happening in your `closeStatement` method

Comment: hmm yeaH the isClosed() fails the test again saying unreachable code

Answer (score 2):

Java is "pass-by-value", which means it creates a copy if the method parameter. To pass an Object, Java copies the reference to that object for use in the method. So when you modify the reference in the method (and this is what you do by assigning 'null' in SybaseDBConnection.closeStatement()) you really only modify the "copy" of the reference. 
After returning, you check if the original is null, but no one touched the original.

Comment: So can you please suggest how i can test it?

Comment: Actually, what Leo said, assertTrue(stmt.isClosed()) should work. However, you're testing the driver there. I'd go for mocking the javax.sql.Statement and check the behaviour of the class by verifying that stmt.close() has actually been called on the mock.

Answer (score 0):

you have created conn varaiable as global i beleive so.can you debug what value is conn getting storfed when you try to create a connection in @beforemethod

```
                 conn = SybaseDBConnection.getConnection("iq");
```